# Camera preview screenshot while camera is running in jellybean

Tags: android, camera, screenshot, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I already saw a few threads which are related to this one, but not identical, so here goes.
I am trying to take a screenshot of a camera preview screen in android jellybean.
It needs to be scriptable, so the volume down + power trick obviously wont work.
Screencap -p , monkeyrunner.takeSnapshot() and so on do not work.

Does anyone have any idea how I can reliably take a screenshot in jellybean?
Please note in ICS, screencap -p worked just fine, but in jellybean, image is corrupt (the new overlay system messed things up).
Thanks in advance
NoamM